# Problems with RVM and Rails when creating new app

Tags: ruby, rvm

When trying doing `rails new myapp`, under this path: `/home/novito/Projectes` I get the following error:

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help.
```

I imagined maybe I created or copied a Rails app in my home folder, so I go there and this is the listing I have when doing `ls -la`

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2012-01-07 18:33 Audiobooks
-rw-r--r--  1 novito novito 604710 2011-06-17 15:54 brasero-session.log
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root     4096 2011-11-26 23:52 build
drwxr-xr-x  5 novito novito   4096 2011-07-26 19:35 bumblebee
d    rwxr-xr-x  6 novito novito   4096 2012-02-15 06:23 config
-rw-r--r--  1 novito novito    157 2012-01-30 21:17 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 19 novito novito   4096 2012-02-15 00:32 Desktop
-rwxr-xr-x  1 novito novito    409 2011-09-18 11:29 django.fcgi
drwxr-xr-x  9 novito novito   4096 2012-02-09 18:35 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito  16384 2012-02-14 03:11 Downloads
drwx------ 10 novito novito   4096 2012-02-13 20:12 Dropbox
-rw-r--r--  1 novito novito    179 2011-06-15 13:39 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2012-01-30 21:41 gmate
drwxr-xr-x  4 novito novito   4096 2011-06-30 11:09 Music
drwxr-xr-x 17 novito novito   4096 2011-08-21 10:27 Música
drwxr-xr-x 10 novito novito   4096 2011-11-01 10:30 netbeans-7.0.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 novito novito   4096 2011-11-01 10:32 NetBeansProjects
drwxr-xr-x  6 novito novito   4096 2011-11-20 16:18 opt
drwxr-xr-x  5 novito novito   4096 2012-01-16 01:57 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 27 novito novito   4096 2012-02-15 06:07 Projectes
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2011-06-15 11:59 Public
-rw-r--r--  1 novito novito   9208 2012-01-30 21:17 README
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2011-12-25 09:49 Schemes
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2012-01-30 21:17 script
drwxr-xr-x  3 novito novito   4096 2011-06-16 23:24 Software
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2011-06-15 11:59 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  8 novito novito   4096 2012-01-30 21:17 test
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2012-02-10 20:24 TESTRAILS
drwxr-xr-x  6 novito novito   4096 2012-01-31 00:41 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2011-06-15 11:56 Ubuntu One
drwxr-xr-x  4 novito novito   4096 2012-01-30 21:17 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  4 novito novito   4096 2012-01-14 16:02 Videos
drwxr-xr-x  2 novito novito   4096 2012-01-07 18:33 Vídeos
drwxr-xr-x  6 novito novito   4096 2011-11-10 22:55 workspace
```

So, I tried deleting config and vendor since they are other rails app related folder... But when I delete config, if I try to do rails new, I get this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- /home/novito/config/boot (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I don't really know what's going on in here, if anyone could give any tips I would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question could be transferred in www.stackoverflow.com

You probably have another rails app in /home/novito/Projectes/ folder.

Check the answer here (I don't know if it's related): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865515/strange-inability-to-require-config-boot-after-upgrading-to-ruby-1-9-2

I don't use ruby/rails, but if the above doesn't work, I think you need to reinstall the ruby version you downloaded with rvm: http://beginrescueend.com/

```
rvm implode
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
rvm requirements # Find the requirements (follow the instructions)
rvm install 1.9.3 # Change 1.9.3 with your version
```

More on rvm (check out "Basics"): http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/

Then try again:

```
reset
mkdir -p /home/novito/Projectes/mynewrailapp
which ruby #check you are using the correct version of ruby
which rails #check you are using the correct version of rails
rails new myapp /home/novito/Projectes/mynewrailapp
```